# Appending a list through if condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

This could be a very basic question, but I realized I am not understanding something.

When appending new things in for loop, how can I raise conditions and still append the item?

For instance:

```
alist = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
new = []
for n in alist:
    if n == 5:
        continue
    else:
        new.append(n+1)

print(new)
```

Gets me

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How do I get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5] # 4 is incremented, 5 is added 'as is'
```

Essentially, I want to tell python to not go through `n+1` when `n==5`.

Would this be the only solution? append n==5 separately in a list and then sum new and the separate list?

Comment: `new.append(n)` rather than `continue`?

Comment: `new = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]`?

Comment: @StephenRauch I'd like to get the result using the for loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just append the `5` instead of using `continue`, is there any other condition?

```
for n in alist:
    if n == 5:
        new.append(n)
    else:
        new.append(n+1)
```

Comment: Right, use append because it appends sequentially! Make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact the a boolean True is 1 while a False is 0 combined with a list comprehension like:

#### Code:

```
[x + int(i != 5) for i, x in enumerate(alist)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
alist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new = [x + int(i != 5) for i, x in enumerate(alist)]
print(new)
```

#### Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't get the point of 'continue'. The Python keyword 'continue', means you do nothing in that if condition, so basically you tell the program "do nothing" when n == 5 and if n is not 5, you do some operation. That's why you got your original result. Hope it may help.